# Warum wird »wohlgesinnt« von »wohlgesonnen« verdrängt?

Tags: colloquial, past-participle, inflection, evolution

Man liest und hört heute häufig den folgenden Satz:

> Er ist mir wohlgesonnen

Nun ist *wohlgesonnen* aber grammatikalisch nicht richtig, denn es muss *wohlgesinnt* heißen. Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wohlgesonnen) listet *wohlgesonnen* demnach auch als umgangssprachlich auf, in vielen Wörterbüchern gibt es *wohlgesonnen* gar nicht.

*Wohlgesinnt* wird aber in der deutschen Sprache zunehmend von *wohlgesonnen* verdrängt:

[image]
<sup>Quelle: [Google Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=wohlgesonnen,wohlgesinnt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3)</sup>

Wie ist es dazu gekommen, dass sich diese Redensart so durchsetzt, und ist es wirklich noch falsch, von *wohlgesonnen* zu reden, wenn es mittlerweile die Mehrheit der Deutschen tut?

Comment: +1 für diese interessante Frage. Ich muss ja zugeben, dass *wohlgesinnt* schon falsch für mich klingt, obwohl es wohl richtig wäre.

Comment: @Deve: genauso geht es mir auch!

Comment: Ist das nicht ein valider Grund für Veränderungen in einer Sprache?

Comment: @musiKk: die ausländischen Deutschlerner werden uns dafür hassen ;)

Comment: Der Graph deutet daraufhin, dass das Wort von den Nazis belastet ist, bei "übel gesinnt" sieht man das besser: http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=%C3%BCbel+gesinnt&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=0

Comment: Ich vermute, dass die eigentlich falsche Variante "wohlgesonnen" in Analogie zum korrekten "versonnen" gebildet wurde. Vgl. https://www.dwds.de/wb/versonnen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In diesem [Blogeintrag von Belles Lettres steht genau zu diesem Thema](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/wohlgesinnt-wohlgesonnen.php) Folgendes, dem ich mich anschließen möchte:

> Nur die Variante wohlgesinnt ist histo­risch rich­tig, wohlgesonnen dagegen un­histo­risch erst vor kur­zem durch eine fal­sche Ver­knüp­fung zum Ver­bum *sinnen* ent­stan­den.
>
> Tatsächlich sind das mittelhochdeutsche *gesinnet* und das neu­zeit­liche *wohlgesinnt* direkt als perfek­tives Adjektiv vom Sub­stan­tiv Sinn ab­gelei­tet, so wie auch das Ad­jek­tiv *gesittet* nicht das Par­ti­zip zu einem nicht­exi­stie­ren­den Ver­bum *sit­ten* ist, sondern vom Sub­stan­tiv *Sitte* ab­gelei­tet ist.
>
> Auch wenn *wohlgesonnen* unhistorisch und durch falsche Ana­logie ent­stan­den ist, ist es gegen­warts­sprach­lich kor­rekt.

Stilistisch kann man heute ruhigen Gewissens sowohl *wohlgesinnt* als auch *wohl­geson­nen* verwenden. Beide Formen sind korrekt und werden von Deutschsprechern ver­wen­det und ver­stan­den, ohne Jar­gon einer Spre­cher­gruppe zu sein.

Comment: "Auch wenn wohlgesonnen unhistorisch und durch falsche Analogie entstanden ist, ist es gegen­wartssprachlich korrekt." Wer sagt das??
Ob nun alles als "gegenwartsprachlich korrekt" bezeichnet werden kann, was sich nur in der Umgangssprache "einbürgert" sei dahingestellt... hochsprachlich ist es darum noch nicht korrekt. Oder sollte man die vielen anderen, wenn nur weit genug verbreiteten Fehler auch als "gegenwartsprachlich korrekt" bezeichnen dürfen? Das Chaos wäre perfekt. Mehrheitliche Übetretung allein kann noch keine Regel beschließen / ändern. Etwa wie im Straßenverkehr - wenn mehrheitli

Comment: @Elkestachel Wo würdest du dann die Grenze ziehen? Unsere Sprache/Hochsprache ist – ob man es akzeptiert oder nicht – nun ständig in Wandlung und enthält vieles, was früher anders verstanden und verwendet wurde. Manchmal wird die Sprache dadurch komplizierter, manchmal einfacher. Aber es ist jedenfalls ein Zeichen, dass sie lebt. Der Hauptzweck einer Sprache ist, dass das Gesprochene und Geschriebene *verstanden* wird, nicht dass sie Paragrafenreitern wie uns gefällt. ;-)

Comment: Was soll das Adjektiv »unhistorisch« in »[ist] dagegen *un­histo­risch* [...] ent­stan­den.«? Wenn eine Variante in der Vergangenheit entstanden ist, dann ist das doch genau die Historie dieser Variante. Was ist daran unhistorisch?

Comment: Strassenverkehr ist ein Super-Beispiel. Da leitet sich die Praxis hoffentlich von der Regel ab, und es gab die Regel, bevor es nennenswerten (im heutigen Sinne) Strassenverkehr gab. Bei Sprachregeln ist es genau andersrum: Die Regel leitet sich aus der *Beobachtung* der Sprache ab. Ja, die Leute konnten schon "richtig" sprechen und schreiben, bevor der Rechtschreibrat das erste Mal tagte....

Answer (score 4):

Die festgeschriebenen Regeln einer Sprache geben nicht vor, wie die Sprecher dieser Sprache zu sprechen haben.

Diese Regeln sind wertvoll, wenn man eine Sprache erlernen will (für jemanden, der Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernt, aber auch für Kinder in der Schule). Aber diese Regeln diktieren nicht, wie jemand, der die Sprache schon gut beherrscht, zu sprechen hat. Anders (weil zutreffender) formuliert: Die Muttersprachler lassen sich durch Regeln in irgendwelchen Büchern nicht vorschrieben, wie sie zu reden haben.

Die Umkehrung trifft nämlich zu: Der tatsächliche Gebrauch der Sprache bestimmt, was richtig und was falsch ist, und bestimmt somit, welche Regeln zu formulieren sind.

Die Sprecher sprechen so, wie sie eben immer sprechen, und machen dabei kleine, mittlere und große Fehler (»Fehler« im Sinn von: »Abweichung von einer festgeschriebenen Regel«). Wenn ein kleiner oder mittlerer Fehler zu keiner Einbuße in der Verständlichkeit führt, wird er vom Empfänger so gut wie nie korrigiert, aber der Empfänger hört eben eine neue Variante, die er genau so gut versteht, und wenn er diese neue Variante nur oft genug hört, wird er sie möglicherweise selbst auch für tauglich halten und aktiv verwenden.

Manchmal pflanzt sich eine falsche Variante sogar wesentlich rascher und nachdrücklicher fort als die richtige, und dann verdrängt die eigentlich falsche Version die richtige Version komplett, wie das gerade gegenwärtig bei der Aussprache des Wortes »Gluten« (»glutenfrei«) passiert.

Dieses Einzahlwort (das Gluten, die Glutene) (eine Eiweißart vor allem in Weizen, die beim Brotbacken bewirkt, dass das Brot nicht bröselig, sondern klebrig wird) sollte eigentlich mit einem kurzen unbetonten u und einem langen und betonten e in der zweiten Silbe ausgesprochen werden ([ɡluˈteːn]), vergleichbar mit der Aussprache vieler anderer zweisilbriger Chemikalien (Benzin, Menthol, Propan, Arsen), die alle auf der langgezogenen Endsilbe betont werden.

Tatsächlich sprechen es aber fast alle (sogar die meisten Nachrichtensprecher) das Wort so aus, als wäre es die Mehrzahl des Wortes Glut (etwas, das so heiß ist, dass es leuchtet) (eine Glut, mehrere Gluten [ɡluːtn̩]).

Ich möchte die Situation auch mit »gewinkt« und »gewunken« im Österreichischen Deutsch vergleichen:

> Lange, nachdem der Zug abgefahren war, hat Elke ihm noch immer nach**gewinkt**.
>   Lange, nachdem der Zug abgefahren war, hat Elke ihm noch immer nach**gewunken**.

Im Österreichischen Deutsch sind beide Varianten schon seit Jahrzehnten Teil der standardisierten Hochsprache, also beide vollkommen korrekt und gleichwertig. Der zweite Satz wird in Österreich (z.B. in einer Schule in Schärding) in einem Schulaufsatz als ebenso richtig bewertet wie der erste. Im Deutschen Deutsch ist nur der erste Satz richtig, der zweite ist falsch und wird in einem Schulaufsatz (z.B. in Passau, nur 10 km von Schärding entfernt) korrigiert, und das, obwohl links und rechts vom Inn dieselbe Umgangssprache gesprochen wird.

In beiden Ländern (auch weit weg von Schärding und Passau) wird »gewunken« in der Umgangssprache verwendet. Der wesentliche Unterschied ist, dass »gewinkt« in den meisten Gebieten Deutschlands häufiger als »gewunken« verwendet wird, während es in Österreich genau umgekehrt ist. Hierzulande würde so gut wie niemand »gewinkt« sagen, daher gilt »gewunken« in Österreich als völlig richtig. »Gewinkt« wird in Österreich eigentlich nur deswegen als korrekt angesehen, weil generell Deutsches Deutsch in Österreich fast immer als richtig gilt, auch dann, wenn im Fall von Unterschieden die deutsche Variante keine praktische Anwendung erfährt.

Der Status von »gewunken« im Österreichischen Deutsch ist ein ganz typisches Beispiel dafür, dass der tatsächliche Gebrauch der Sprache darüber bestimmt, was richtig und was falsch ist.

Im Fall von »wohlgesonnen« wird der Duden wohl irgendwann denselben Schritt gehen, denn das ÖWB (Österreichisches Wörterbuch, das ist das amtliche Regelwerk für Österreichisches Deutsch) im Fall von »gewunken« schon vor Jahrzehnten gegangen ist: Der Status des Wortes wird von »umgangssprachlich« auf »standardsprachlich« geändert werden.

Vermutlich wird irgendwann auch die weitaus häufigere (aber jetzt noch als falsch geltende) Aussprache von »Gluten« offiziell als richtig akzeptiert.

Comment: Betreffend _Gluten_: Meine Beobachtung, in Deutschland, ist genau umgekehrt („alle“ betonen die zweite Silbe, analog zu _Propen_, _Benzen_ usw.). Ebenfalls würde ich die „historisch korrekte“ Aussprache genau umgekehrt ansetzen, d.h. Betonung der ersten Silbe ist „korrekt“, da es sich eben nicht um eine chemische Kunstbezeichnung handelt, sondern um das lateinische Wort _gluten_ (‘Klebstoff’) mit natürlicher Betonung auf der ersten Silbe. (Dagegen z.B. _Arsen_ aus lat. _arsenicum_ mit natürlicher Betonung auf _sen_.)

Comment: @chirlu: Das ist mir eine eigene Frage wert: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/29886/1487

Comment: Viel Text, fast nichts zu „wohlgesonnen“. Es war wohl als Replik auf Antwort von Elohim gedacht. Dass das unangemessen ist, weißt Du eigentlich, es kümmert Dich aber nicht.

Comment: Ich habe noch nirgendwo in Deutschland *gewinkt* gehört, und **immer** wenn ich es aus historischen Gründen benütze, werde ich mit *gewunken* verbessert …