# Aussprache von »Gluten«

Tags: pronunciation, loanword

Kurze und einfache Frage:

Wie wird das Wort »Gluten«, mit dem ein Eiweißstoff bezeichnet wird, der in vielen Getreidesorten zu finden ist, richtig ausgesprochen?

Zur Auswahl stehen:

- [ɡluˈteːn], also erste Silbe mit kurzem unbetontem u, und die zweite Silbe mit langem und betontem e.
- [ˈɡluːtn̩], also erste Silbe mit langem und betontem u, während die zweite Silbe nur aus einem t und einem vokalisierten n besteht und unbetont ist.

---

Ich halte die erste Version ([ɡluˈteːn]) für richtig, und zwar aus diesen Gründen:

Gluten ist eine Chemikalie (auch wenn es sich dabei um einen natürlich vorkommenden Stoff handelt), wenn auch kein Reinstoff. (Der handelsübliche Zucker wäre so ein chemischer Reinstoff, weil er zu 100% aus einer einzigen chemischen Verbindung besteht). Gluten ist ein Gemisch aus verschiedenen Eiweißmolekülen, vergleichbar mit Benzin, das ebenfalls ein Gemisch verschiedener Moleküle (in diesem Fall Kohlenwasserstoffe) ist.

Solche Stoffe werden immer mit langgezogener und betonter Endsilbe gesprochen:

- Benzin
- Menthol
- Propan
- Strychnin
- Arsen
- Azeton

Die andere Betonung ([ˈɡluːtn̩]) deutet auf ein Mehrzahlwort (Mehrzahl von *Glut*) hin, was es aber nicht ist. Es gibt das Gluten (Einzahl), das als Stoffname eigentlich ein Singularetantum ist. Vergleichbar mit Sanden, Wässern und Erden, mit denen Sandarten, Wasserarten und Erdarten gemeint sind, kann man unterschiedlichen Glutenarten aber auch als Glutene (Mehrzahl) bezeichnen.

Ich war mir bis vor kurzem relativ sicher, [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gluten) und [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gluten) bestärken mich auch, doch ein Kommentar auf eine andere [Frage hier auf German.SE](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/29875/1487) lässt mich zweifeln, weshalb ich hier mal nachfrage.

Comment: Ich denke, du darfst dir sicher bleiben... Genauso, wie die "bösen" Glutene in den letzten Jahren durchs Land ziehen, wird es auch Mode, das Wort "englisch" auszusprechen...

Comment: Was fragst Du, ob die Wörterbücher irren?

Comment: @CarstenS: Ich gratuliere: Du hast die Frage verstanden!

Comment: "Der handelsübliche Zucker wäre so ein chemischer Reinstoff, weil er zu 100% aus einer einzigen chemischen Verbindung besteht." Das wär schon schön, ist aber nicht so. Zucker ist eine Stoffklasse und der handelsübliche Zucker besteht hauptsächlich aus Saccharose.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン: Handelsüblicher Zucker besteht nicht "hauptsächlich", sondern "ausschließlich", also zu genau 100%, aus chemisch reiner Saccharose. Saccharose wiederum ist eine chemische Verbindung mit dem systematischen Namen (2R,3R,4S,5S,6R)-2-[(2S,3S,4S,5R)-3,4-dihydroxy-2,5-bis(hydroxymethyl)oxolan-2-yl]oxy-6-(hydroxymethyl)oxane-3,4,5-triol. Handeslüblicher Zucker ist die einzige Chemikalie, die man im Supermarkt in einer Reinheit bekommt, die der Chemiker als »rein (purum)« bezeichnet. Nicht einmal Wasser oder Kochsalz werden so rein verkauft.

Comment: Wieder was, was ich während meines langjährigem Chemiestudiums falsch gelernt habe.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン: Ich habe das schon während der Chemie-Olympiade, an der ich in den 1980ern teilgenommen habe, gelernt, und dann natürlich noch einmal während meines Chemie-Studiums an der Karl-Franzens-Uni in Graz. Das Chemie-Studium habe ich zugegebenermaßen abgebrochen, aber das Praktikum für Organische Chemie habe ich fertig gemacht (und dabei natürlich das Organikum mehr oder weniger auswendig gelernt).

Comment: Ich weiß, Wikipedia ist keine sehr zuverlässige Quelle, ["rein (purum >95%)"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zucker#Zusammensetzung) scheint aber trotzdem zu stimmen - zumindest für den Organiker.

Comment: ich würde mir bei einer Strassenbaufirma eine Betonmaschine ausleihen...

Comment: @HubertSchölnast   *Chemie ist, wenn man trotzdem lacht.* (Alte Spruchweisheit)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン: Das Wort „Zucker“ hat *zwei* Bedeutungen. Einerseits bezeichnet es den Stoff Saccharose (Haushaltszucker), andererseits bezeichnet es die Stoffklasse, zu der außer Saccharose auch noch Glukose (Traubenzucker) und Fruktose (Fruchtzucker) gehören (und möglicherweise auch andere Stoffe). Wenn bei einem Lebensmittel Zucker als Zutat angegeben ist, dann bedeutet das Saccharose; wenn in der Ernährungsinformation der Gehalt an Zucker angegeben ist („Kohlehydrate, davon Zucker“), dann bedeutet das die Stoffklasse.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Im Deutschen ist formal [ɡluˈteːn] korrekt, da ist m.E. Deiner Recherche nichts hinzuzufügen, *aber* da die englische Aussprache eben [ˈɡluːtn̩] ist, scheint sich hier per verstecktem Anglizismus diese Aussprache einzuschleichen.

*Satire*
Zu unterscheiden ist vielleicht auch – mal ganz zynisch unterstellt – zwischen den Menschen, die an Zöliakie leiden und daher [ɡluˈteːn] meiden müssen, und denen, die einem Ernährungstrend hinterherrennen und das böse [ˈɡluːtn̩] nicht essen wollen.
*\Satire*

Comment: das lateinische Ursprungswort *gluten* wird aber auch mit langem/betontem u ausgesprochen, letztlich weicht Deutsch hier vom Standard ab. Glut'n klingt in meinen Ohren aber auch seltsam Gluteen is besser.. For the Glory of Saitan!

Comment: Ich denke nur an Halogen, Hydrogen, Ibuprofen, kariogen, Propen oder Propylen, Ethylen, schizophren, Phänomen, Isopren, Athen ( :-), usw. Die werden alle mit -een gesprochen. Gluten gehört auch zu dieser Gruppe. Es wäre m.E. lächerlich es als "Glut'n" auszusprechen (oder z.B. Ethylen als "Ethyl'n").

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis  <albernheit> *Firmichbistuscheen* wird auch mit langem e gesprochen. </albernheit>

Comment: @Christian: ist wohl verwandt mit [Beimirbistushein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bei_Mir_Bistu_Shein). <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis   Ja, Firmichbistusheen ist bekantermaßen ein Derivat des Beimirbistusheins. Allerdings wird letzteres korrekt dann auch *Beimirbistushe-iin* ausgesprochen, also wie das Koffein.

Comment: Möglicherweise kommt es darauf an, wovon man genau spricht. Mir ist die Auffassung begegnet, dass [ɡluˈteːn] die Bezeichnung für den Stoff (bzw. das Gemisch aus einer Reihe von Stoffen) ist, und [ˈɡluːtn̩] die Bezeichnung für die Stärkekörnchen, in denen das [ɡluˈteːn] im Getreidekorn vorliegt. Wie etabliert diese Unterscheidung ist, kann ich aber nicht sagen.

Answer (score 8):

Hier stellt sich zunächst das Problem, was man überhaupt als „richtig“ ansehen will. Wenn man einfach dem Duden folgt, ist die „richtige“ Aussprache [ɡluˈteːn]; Fall erledigt.¹ Ansonsten kann man sich nach dem richten, was der durchschnittliche Muttersprachler tut. Das ist hier allerdings schwierig, da *Gluten* ein Fachwort ist, das vermutlich bei der Mehrzahl der Sprecher gar nicht in Gebrauch ist; und bei dem Anteil, der es verwendet, konkurrieren offenkundig zwei verschiedene Aussprachemöglichkeiten, nämlich [ɡluˈteːn] und [ˈɡluːtn̩].

Wenn man sich also nicht einfach dem Duden anschließen will, kann man nur noch die Herkunft des Wortes betrachten. Für Fremdwörter – insbesondere aus den klassischen, prestigeträchtigen Sprachen – ist es im Deutschen nämlich verbreitet, die Originalbetonung möglichst zu erhalten. So kommt es zu der Betonung von Wörtern wie *Natúr* (lat. *natúra*), *modérn* (frz. *moderne*), *akut* (lat. *acútus*), Bibliothék (griech. *bibliothéke*), *Kásus* (lat. *cásus*), *Arsén* (lat. *arsénicum*) usw. Strikt durchgehalten wird das Prinzip, wie immer bei sprachlichen Entwicklungen, allerdings nicht. Es gibt auch Fälle, in denen z.B. ein ursprünglich griechisches Wort ins Lateinische und daraus ins Französische übernommen wurde; da die Betonungsregeln der drei Sprachen sich unterscheiden, hängt die Betonung im Deutschen auch davon ab, welche der drei Sprachen gerade bevorzugt wurde.

Die diversen „chemischen“ Endungen wie *-an* (für Kohlenwasserstoffketten mit Einfachbindungen), *-en* (mit Doppelbindungen), *-in* (mit Dreifachbindungen), *-ol* (für Alkohole), *-al* (für Aldehyde) usw., mit denen heute nach der IUPAC-[Nomenklatur](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomenklatur_%28Chemie%29) organische Verbindungen systematisch benannt werden, stammen aus sehr unterschiedlichen Quellen. Ob nun historisch korrekt oder nicht, hat sich hier aber die Endbetonung der mit diesen Suffixen gebildeten Benennungen ganz klar durchgesetzt: *Ethán*, *Ethanól*, *Ethén* usw.

Nicht in allen chemischen Bezeichnungen, die auf *-an* oder *-en* enden, liegt aber tatsächlich ein solches IUPAC-Suffix vor. *Arsen* als ein Beispiel habe ich oben schon aufgeführt: Es stammt vom lateinischen *arsénicum* ab, dessen ursprüngliche Endsilben im Deutschen in zwei Schritten wegfielen (*Arsenik*, *Arsen*). Tatsächlich ist Arsen ein chemisches Element und kein Kohlenwasserstoff mit Doppelbindung. Die gleiche (End-)Betonung ist Zufall.

Entsprechendes gilt für *Gluten*, einen Eiweißstoff. Sein Name leitet sich aus dem lateinischen Wort *glúten* ab (Genitiv *glútinis*; Neutrum), das ‘Klebstoff’ bedeutet (davon auch das englische *glue*). Mit dem IUPAC-Suffix *-en* hat es nichts zu tun; und anders als bei *Arsen* fällt die Betonung auch nicht zufällig auf die Silbe *-en*.

Wenn man der traditionellen Vorgehensweise folgen möchte, die Originalbetonung beizubehalten, wird man also *Glúten* [ˈɡluːtn̩] als die sprachhistorisch korrekte Aussprache ansehen, wohingegen die Form *Glutén* [ɡluˈteːn] durch die Anlehnung an „falsche Freunde“ wie *Arsen* und *Ethen* entstanden ist.

---

¹ Mittlerweile, Anfang 2021, hat es die Anfangsbetonung allerdings auch auf die Duden-Seite geschafft. Dort heißt es zur Aussprache jetzt: „[ɡluˈteːn], auch: [ˈɡluːtn̩]“

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120030/discussion-on-answer-by-chirlu-aussprache-von-gluten).

Answer (score 2):

Glú:ten mit Betonung auf der ersten Silbe hat im Deutschen zwei Klangrivalen: das Verbum blú:ten und die oben erwähnte Mehrzahl des Substantivs Glut (Glú:ten). Anders als im Niederländischen oder Englischen oder in anderen Sprachen herrscht dadurch im Deutschen ein Wortumfeld, das die meisten Sprecher instinktiv dazu veranlasst, "Glu:tén" zu sagen und die klangliche Assoziation mit "blúten" und "Glúten" zu vermeiden. Dadurch wird das Wort etymologisch vielleicht falsch, aber inhaltlich zutreffend mit einer Reihe ähnlich lautender Chemikalien assoziiert, und der Hörer weiß schon durch die Betonung, was gemeint ist und was nicht. - Über "Glú:ten" stolpert doch jeder, oder? Na also.

Comment: Mir ist nicht ganz klar, wie die Akzente und Doppelpunkte zu interpretieren sind. Ich weis nicht, worin genau der Unterschied zwischen den drei Varianten Glú:ten, Glu:tén und Glúten liegen soll. Bitte verwende das internationale phonetische Alphabet (IPA) um die Aussprache wiederzugeben. Dabei bedeutet das Zeichen ˈ vor einer Silbe, dass darauf folgende Silbe zu betonen ist. Silben ohne dieses vorangesetzte Zeichen sind unbetont. Das Zeichen ː hinter einem Vokal bedeutet, dass der davor stehende Vokal lang auszusprechen ist. Vokale ohne diese Markierung sind kurz zu sprechen.

Comment: Und ein kurzer senkrechter Strich unter einem sonoren Konsonanten in einer Silbe ohne Vokal bedeutet, dass dieser Konsonant der Gipfel bzw. Kern dieser Silbe ist, dass also dieser Konsonant anstelle eines Vokals für den Klang der Silbe sorgt.

Answer (score 1):

Den naturwissenschaftlichen Begründungen der Aussprache kann ich erstmal nicht hinzufügen. Die Betonung auf dem "e" von Gluten ist auch von einer anderen, eher sprachlichen Seite her sinnvoll: Es ist einfach praktischer, wenn der Holzofenbäcker in seinen Fachgesprächen einen hörbaren Unterschied zwischen dem im Brot enthaltenen Gluten und den in seinem Ofen wabernden Gluten machen kann.
Ich vermute, dass die deutsche Angewohnheit, diese chemische Stoffklasse wie oben beschrieben auszusprechen, unter Anderem mit dem Vorhandensein eines anderen gleich geschriebenen Wortes begründbar ist.

Comment: Ich vermute eher dass der Name Gluten analog ist an vielen anderen Wörtern die auf *-en* enden, z.B. Ibuprofen, Halogen, Hydrogen, allogen, psychogen, usw. Diese werden alle mit "-een" gesprochen.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Deine 5 Beispielen enthalten 4 Worte mit derselben griechischen Endsilbe (*»-gen«* = bilden, erzeugen): Halogen = Salzbildner/Salzerzeuger , Hydrogen = Wasserbildner/Wassererzeuger, allogen = woanders gebildet/erzeugt, psychogen = in der Psyche gebildet/erzeugt

Comment: @Hubert: schon, aber ich habe in einem anderen Kommentar noch Phänomen, schizophren, Propylen, Isopren, usw. genannt. Die mit -gen waren nur die ersten, die mir in den Kopf kamen. Und ich weiß, was -gen bedeutet. Hatte Alt-Griechisch als Endexamenfach (eins von insgesamt acht, damals in den Niederlanden).

Comment: Meine Antwort war als Ergänzung gedacht. Natürlich ist der Wissenschafts-affine Klang des Wortes mit langem "e", der durch die von Rudy Velthuis angeführten Worte (und die Liste ließe sich sicher noch verlängern) zustande kommt, eine Grund für die Entstehung dieser Aussprache. Ich denke allerdings, dass das Vorhandensein eines gleich klingenden Wortes anderer Bedeutung diesen Prozess extrem begünstigt.

Answer (score 0):

Ganz klar: Wer Gluten in einem Atemzug mit schizophren nennt, ist einem falschen Freund aufgesessen. "Schizophren" ist griechisch, daher gelten keine lateinischen Betonungsregeln.

Ibuprofen ist ein Handelsname, der aus folgendem schönen Begriff gebildet wurde: 
2-(4-Isobutylphenyl)propionsäure

Im Ursprungswort ist tatsächlich das "phen" eine der betonten Silben.

Davon hat der Hersteller das I von Iso, das bu von butyl, das phen aus phenyl genommen, dann noch das pro aus propion.

Damit wäre der eigentliche Name "Ibuphenpro". Klingt bescheuert. Dachte sich wohl auch der Hersteller und hat die zwei letzten Silben getauscht. Und da nun am Ende das durchaus betonte "phen" lag, hat er das als Hauptbetonung gewählt- wohl auch in Anklang an "Arsen" und "karzinogen".

Das ist aber eine Entscheidung des Herstellers gewesen und hat mit Sprache so mal gar nichts zu tun. Das wäre so, wie wenn man von "Die Billa" (österr. Supermarkt im REWE Konzern) reden wollte, weil auf "-a" endende Worte meist romanischen Ursprungs und meist weiblich sind. Aber der Name Billa ist ein Handelsname, eine Marke, und hat keinen romanischen Ursprung.

Phänomen, im Griechischen Phainomenon, wird im Griechischen auf -nom- betont. Der Wegfall der Endsilbe wird dadurch angedeutet, dass die letzte verbleibende Silbe betont wird.

Dagegen gibt es im Lateinischen eine ganze Menge Worte auf "-en", wie zum Beispiel: 
Nomen
Lumen
Numen

In diese Kategorie gehört auch Gluten. Es ist ein Neutrum, wie die anderen drei auch, und damit würde, wo erforderlich, der Plural auch genau so gebildet, wie bei Nomen (Nomina), Lumen (Lumina) und Numen (Numina). Also Glutina.

Gluten als krankmachenden Stoff kennt man wohl erst seit den 1950ern, als Willem Karel Dicke die Zöliakie und Getreide in Verbindung brachte. Und da im ganzen Rest der Welt, inklusive den Niederlanden, von Glu:ten gesprochen wird, nehme ich an, dass deutschsprachige Chemiker gefunden haben, dass Glu:ten sehr banal klingt, die Betonung auf der Endsilbe aber sehr gebildet.

Comment: Was genau haben die ersten sieben Absätze mit der gestellten Frage zu tun? Ich kann mich nicht erinnern, nach *»schizophren«, »Ibuprophen«* oder *»Phänomen«* gefragt zu haben. Diese Begriffe hat jemand in Kommentaren zu anderen Fragen eingeworfen, und wenn du darauf eingehen willst, dann bitte eben dort: In den Kommentaren. Und was das Geschlecht vom *»Billa«* mit all dem zu tun hat, erschließt sich mir auch nicht.

Comment: Wenn das hier ein Latein-Forum wäre, hättest du vermutlich recht mit der Bildung des Plurals, der dann auf -a enden müsste. Das ist aber nicht der Fall. Wir reden hier von der deutschen Sprache. Ich muss nicht Japanisch können um den Plural von *Kimono* bilden zu können, kein Arabisch für den Plural von *Algebra* und kein Inuktitut um den Plural von *Iglu* zu bilden. Obwohl keines dieser Wörter ein deutsches Wort ist, werden sie alle nach den Regeln der deutschen Sprache dekliniert. Und das trifft in der Regel auch auf lateinische Wörter zu, wiewohl es hier zugegebenermaßen Ausnahmen gibt.

Comment: Dein Schlusssatz *»Und jetzt haben wir den Salat«* fasst zwar den aktuellen Zustand recht gut zusammen, aber weder dieser Schlusssatz, noch sonst etwas in deinem Posting beantwortet meine Frage, die ich hier gerne noch einmal wiederhole (zweiter Absatz aus meinem Frage-Posting): **Wie wird das Wort »Gluten« [...] richtig ausgesprochen?**