# wohlgesonnen oder wohlgesinnt + Verwendung

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Ich lese die Antworte auf [diese frühere Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/warum-wird-wohlgesinnt-von-wohlgesonnen-verdr%C3%A4ngt) mit grossem Interesse. Meine Frage stimmt mit der vorherigen überein, aber betrifft auch die Verwendung und Aufbau im Satz.

Sind die folgenden Sätze korrekt ?

> Obwohl direkte Verwandte oft **wohlgesinnt** sind, erweisen sie sich nicht immer als gute Ratgeber.

Ich verstehe, dass wohlgesonnen umgangsprachlicher und neurer wirkt, aber nicht wirklich falsch ist: Zumindest wird das Wort durch seinen Verbrauch gerechfertigt oder legitimiert.

> Obwohl direkte Verwandte oft **wohlgesonnen** sind, erweisen sie sich nicht immer als gute Ratgeber.

Aber muss der Aufbau von wohlgesinnt oder wohlgesonnen unbedingt ein Dativobjekt aufweisen?

> Obwohl direkte Verwandte **einem** oft **wohlgesinnt** sind, erweisen sie sich nicht immer als gute Ratgeber.

bzw.

> Obwohl direkte Verwandte **einem** oft **wohlgesonnen** sind, erweisen sie sich nicht immer als gute Ratgeber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Wohlgesinnt* *sein* ist eine pure Eigenschaft, die kein bestimmtes Objekt oder Ziel hat - sie ist also intransitiv.

*jemandem wohlgesinnt sein* hat dagegen ein Objekt - hier dient der Dativ dazu, aus einer eigentlich *intransitiven* Konstruktion eine *transitive* zu machen. Das ist eine aus der lateinischen Grammatik übernommene Konstruktion, die es erlaubt, mit einem eigentlich intransitiven Verb eine transitive Aussage zumachen.